# "der Satz": How to disambiguate the two linguistic meanings?

Tags: single-word-request, noun

The word *Satz* can mean, among other things:

- Clause: "A verb along with its subject and their modifiers."
- Sentence: "A grammatically complete series of words consisting of a subject and predicate, even if one or the other is implied, and typically beginning with a capital letter and ending with a full stop."

This can lead to problems when discussing languages. Today, I failed the assignment "Schreiben Sie einen Satz", by writing a sentence instead of a clause. What other words could be used instead of *Satz* for these meanings in order to avoid this problem?

Comment: I realise that this is not a single word request, but I didn't want to create the double-word-request tag.

Comment: @Tim I think that you have to give more information on your assignment. I have great doubts that it was just "Schreiben Sie einen Satz".

Comment: @thei: The question is independent of the anecdote. I want words that the teacher could have used instead of _Satz_ to clearly distinguish the two possible interpretations of the assignment.

Comment: @thei: The actual assignment was "Schreiben Sie bitte einen langen Satz", which was supposed to have a pedagogic point regarding adverbs.

Comment: @Tim So the point was to write a sentence that contained more than one clause?

Comment: @thei: The point was to write a clause that contained many adverbs (and thus was long). I wrote a sentence with more than one clause, because I thought the _Satz_ in the assigment meant _sentence_, not _clause_.

Comment: @Tim Please write the complete assignment phrase and a supposedly correct answer.

Comment: @thei: Sorry, it was given orally. I've approximated it as good as I can. Good answer: "Er spielt oft mit seiner Freundin Tennis". Bad answer: "Er spielt Tennis mit seiner Freundin, die ein Rock trägt". I could edit out the assignment sentence of my question if you like; it really should not affect the answer. I'm asking: How to translate "clause" and "sentence" unambiguously?

Comment: @Tim Basically, if your teacher wanted you to write a sentence with an adverb he may or may not have communicated this, but the problem here is not with the word "Satz". If anything, it was with the word "lang".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A random google result:

> Dieser Satz besteht aus einem Hauptsatz und einem kausalen Nebensatz, der zwei Partizipialsätze enthält.

At the moment, I cannot think of a *linguistic* situation where the single word "Satz" means clause and not sentence. So I am awaiting more details on your assignment to clear up this problem.

In a linguistic context, "Satz" means "sentence" and "clause" means

ling. Satzteil {m}

ling. Teilsatz {m}

ling. Gliedsatz {m}

ling. Nebensatz {m}

ling. satzwertige Konstruktion {f}

as cited from dict.cc

There is no ambiguity, so I don't really know what else to say.

There may have been some other incompleteness in the teacher's assignment, but demanding a long sentence does not imply a demand of a sentence with a sub-clause.

Edited to add:

A sentence without a sub-clause is a "einfacher Satz", but I think that the point of your anecdote is that your teacher gave his own ad-hoc definition of "langer Satz" before (maybe in your absence). And it is this definition of "long" which is the problem here.

Comment: [dict.cc translates "Satz" to "clause".](http://www.dict.cc/?s=satz) Also, it makes sense that a Nebensatz is a Satz.

Comment: @Tim I suggest that you click on clause and read: ling. Satzteil {m}
ling. Teilsatz {m}
ling. Gliedsatz {m}
ling. Nebensatz {m}
ling. satzwertige Konstruktion {f}, *all* the "ling" entries point to other words.

Comment: The first translation is still "Satz {m}", even if it doesn't get a "ling". Perhaps it's understood in a linguistic context, but in the example above, I still hold that "Satz" is ambiguous.

Comment: No, if you say "Schreiben Sie einen langen Satz", it does not mean "Write a long clause".

Comment: Definitely not ambiguous. "Satz" always refers to a sentence.

Comment: I think that's rather a mistake in the dictionary.

Comment: @Tim : Your example is not ambiguous. There are indeed situations where "Satz" can be translated to "clause". However, that would never be in a linguistic context but more likely when referring for example to a legal "clause". From what you've written here so far, your teacher did either not word the question correctly, or the reason why your answer was rejected had nothing to do with your addition of a relative clause at all (e.g. in your comment where you gave the "bad" example you got the case wrong: it should have been "einen Rock").

Comment: Thanks, everyone seems to agree that _Satz_ is unambiguous. I'll ask my teacher if I misunderstood the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that your teacher needs to further analyze her word choices. *Satz* is used in German to refer to a phrase. Contrary to current word use, in English, the word *phrase* can be utilized in reference to either a complete thought or an incomplete thought, which is either spoken or written. With time, we have come to use the word *phrase,* and other words like *clause,* more often when talking about incomplete thoughts; on the other hand, we have begun to use the word *sentence* to refer to full thoughts.

This, however, is part of **English** and its changes – German has evolved differently. We can think of the German word *Satz* as *phrase.* In order to clarify that we are talking about a complete thought, we can add a more specific descriptor, such as *Haupt-* to form *Hauptsatz (main phrase);* in the case of an incomplete thought, we can use the descriptor *Neben-* to form *Nebensatz.* If your teacher simply wrote *Satz,* she was not being specific as to what she wanted, and she cannot expect you to come up with subordinate clauses if she simply said *write phrases.* In my book, and I speak as a fellow teacher, she’d be the one getting a poor evaluation as a German instructor.